# Redirecting to other page ? In asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net], i write the code to redirect to other page with in the solution, but it is giving exception.

```
 Response.Redirect("abc.aspx");
```

can you help me, thank you.

```
   WeeklyAttendanceMailStatusBE obj = new WeeklyAttendanceMailStatusBE();

            obj.CreatedBy = Session["xxx"].ToString();
            obj.Sesssionid = Session.SessionID.ToString();
            obj.StatusDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
            obj.Types = "Insert";

            if (radLastWeek.Checked == true)
            {
                obj.Flags = 1;
                obj.LastWeekStatus = 1;
                int result = new WeeklyAttendanceMailStatusBL().InsertWeeklyAttendanceMailStatus(obj);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("abc.html");

                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", "<script> alert('Not Submited Mail Status')</status>", false); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
```

Comment: what exception are you getting ? is there a page called abc.aspx ?

Comment: {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: Try closing VS instances and try again.

Comment: please write more code that are surrounded with this code coz this can not be caused any exception other that error 404

Comment: lack of detail, please add more of your code and describe what are u trying to do.

Comment: dont think about how i get points, think about to solve problem guys,

Comment: @Suryasasidhar We aren't being paid to solve your problems, so be grateful for the help you get and learn to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is because of "thread is being aborted" exception, handle exception with try catch statements or specific catch class called **ThreadAbortException**

Please refer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/984756.aspx/1) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Response.Redirect("abc.aspx",false);
```

Add a second argument (boolean value) that indicates whether to stop running the current page.
Reference :
[HOW TO: Use Response.Redirect in ASP.NET with Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312063)